# One hour layover sufficient to get through customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, layovers, amsterdam

I am flying from Oslo to the US on 25 Feb 2013 with a one hour layover in Amsterdam. My flight arrives at 11:50 AM. Is one hour enough time to get through customs? I am a US citizen and I am booked Delta/KLM as a single ticket.

Comment: surely you're not actually going through customs, just transit?

Comment: @Mark: Norway is Schengen Zone, but not UE, so he might be selected for random customs check. And for outgoing flight he has to go through passport check (going from Schengen part of airport into non-Schengen).